# Python & YoutubeDL, retrive info-json, modify it and work with it

Tags: python, json, youtube-dl

I need to work with only a part of the info-json that youtubedl obtains: the problem is in a video platform where, in the browser, you can watch the video or download/hear the audio file (that is besides the internal audio files from the video, like the "visual" option and the "podcast" option).
The problem is that it downloads both files (video+audio), this is how I obtain the info:

```
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'retries': 10 })
result = ydl.extract_info(vurl, download=False)
```

Where `vurl` is the video url; the json that I get in `result` is:

```
{
    "_type": "playlist",
    "entries": [
        {
            "formats": [
                {
                    "format_id": "3",
                    "manifest_url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556.mpd",
                    "ext": "m4a",
                    "width": null,
                    "height": null,
                    "tbr": 96.0,
                    "asr": 48000,
                    "fps": null,
                    "language": "eng",
                    "format_note": "DASH audio",
                    "filesize": null,
                    "container": "m4a_dash",
                    "vcodec": "none",
                    "acodec": "mp4a.40.5",
                    "url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556_audio.mp4",
                    "http_headers": {
                        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3680.1 Safari/537.36",
                        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                        "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
                        "Referer": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9"
                    },
                    "format": "3 - audio only (DASH audio)",
                    "protocol": "https"
                },
                {
                    "format_id": "2",
                    "manifest_url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556.mpd",
                    "ext": "mp4",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 270,
                    "tbr": 350.0,
                    "asr": null,
                    "fps": null,
                    "language": null,
                    "format_note": "DASH video",
                    "filesize": null,
                    "container": "mp4_dash",
                    "vcodec": "avc1.4d401f",
                    "acodec": "none",
                    "url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556_270.mp4",
                    "http_headers": {
                        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3680.1 Safari/537.36",
                        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                        "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
                        "Referer": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9"
                    },
                    "format": "2 - 480x270 (DASH video)",
                    "protocol": "https"
                },
                {
                    "format_id": "1",
                    "manifest_url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556.mpd",
                    "ext": "mp4",
                    "width": 960,
                    "height": 540,
                    "tbr": 1500.0,
                    "asr": null,
                    "fps": null,
                    "language": null,
                    "format_note": "DASH video",
                    "filesize": null,
                    "container": "mp4_dash",
                    "vcodec": "avc1.640028",
                    "acodec": "none",
                    "url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556_540.mp4",
                    "http_headers": {
                        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3680.1 Safari/537.36",
                        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                        "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
                        "Referer": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9"
                    },
                    "format": "1 - 960x540 (DASH video)",
                    "protocol": "https"
                },
                {
                    "format_id": "hls-219",
                    "url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/hls/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556_270.m3u8",
                    "manifest_url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/hls/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556.m3u8",
                    "tbr": 219.293,
                    "ext": "mp4",
                    "fps": 14.985,
                    "protocol": "m3u8",
                    "preference": null,
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 270,
                    "vcodec": "avc1.4d401f",
                    "acodec": "mp4a.40.5",
                    "http_headers": {
                        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3680.1 Safari/537.36",
                        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                        "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
                        "Referer": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9"
                    },
                    "format": "hls-219 - 480x270"
                },
                {
                    "format_id": "hls-475",
                    "url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/hls/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556_540.m3u8",
                    "manifest_url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/hls/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556.m3u8",
                    "tbr": 475.81,
                    "ext": "mp4",
                    "fps": 29.97,
                    "protocol": "m3u8",
                    "preference": null,
                    "width": 960,
                    "height": 540,
                    "vcodec": "avc1.4d401f",
                    "acodec": "mp4a.40.5",
                    "http_headers": {
                        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3680.1 Safari/537.36",
                        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                        "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
                        "Referer": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9"
                    },
                    "format": "hls-475 - 960x540"
                }
            ],
            "subtitles": {},
            "thumbnail": "https://photos.brighteon.com/file/brighteon-thumbnails/poster/05fc220c-5fa5-4ac5-b2e4-96229bce92cf",
            "id": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9-1",
            "title": "Situation Update, 10/24/22 - Dirty bomb false flag event to IGNITE World War with Russia (1)",
            "n_entries": 2,
            "playlist": "Situation Update, 10/24/22 - Dirty bomb false flag event to IGNITE World War with Russia",
            "playlist_id": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9",
            "playlist_title": "Situation Update, 10/24/22 - Dirty bomb false flag event to IGNITE World War with Russia",
            "playlist_uploader": null,
            "playlist_uploader_id": null,
            "playlist_index": 1,
            "extractor": "generic",
            "webpage_url": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9",
            "webpage_url_basename": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9",
            "extractor_key": "Generic",
            "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "url": "https://photos.brighteon.com/file/brighteon-thumbnails/poster/05fc220c-5fa5-4ac5-b2e4-96229bce92cf",
                    "id": "0"
                }
            ],
            "display_id": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9-1",
            "requested_subtitles": null,
            "requested_formats": [
                {
                    "format_id": "1",
                    "manifest_url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556.mpd",
                    "ext": "mp4",
                    "width": 960,
                    "height": 540,
                    "tbr": 1500.0,
                    "asr": null,
                    "fps": null,
                    "language": null,
                    "format_note": "DASH video",
                    "filesize": null,
                    "container": "mp4_dash",
                    "vcodec": "avc1.640028",
                    "acodec": "none",
                    "url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556_540.mp4",
                    "http_headers": {
                        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3680.1 Safari/537.36",
                        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                        "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
                        "Referer": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9"
                    },
                    "format": "1 - 960x540 (DASH video)",
                    "protocol": "https"
                },
                {
                    "format_id": "3",
                    "manifest_url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556.mpd",
                    "ext": "m4a",
                    "width": null,
                    "height": null,
                    "tbr": 96.0,
                    "asr": 48000,
                    "fps": null,
                    "language": "eng",
                    "format_note": "DASH audio",
                    "filesize": null,
                    "container": "m4a_dash",
                    "vcodec": "none",
                    "acodec": "mp4a.40.5",
                    "url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/dash/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556_audio.mp4",
                    "http_headers": {
                        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3680.1 Safari/537.36",
                        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                        "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
                        "Referer": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9"
                    },
                    "format": "3 - audio only (DASH audio)",
                    "protocol": "https"
                }
            ],
            "format": "1 - 960x540 (DASH video)+3 - audio only (DASH audio)",
            "format_id": "1+3",
            "width": 960,
            "height": 540,
            "resolution": null,
            "fps": null,
            "vcodec": "avc1.640028",
            "vbr": null,
            "stretched_ratio": null,
            "acodec": "mp4a.40.5",
            "abr": null,
            "ext": "mp4"
        },
        {
            "formats": [
                {
                    "ext": "mp3",
                    "width": null,
                    "height": null,
                    "tbr": null,
                    "format_id": "0",
                    "url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/audio/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556.mp3",
                    "vcodec": "none",
                    "http_headers": {
                        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3680.1 Safari/537.36",
                        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                        "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
                        "Referer": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9"
                    },
                    "format": "0 - audio only",
                    "protocol": "https"
                }
            ],
            "subtitles": {},
            "thumbnail": null,
            "id": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9-2",
            "title": "Situation Update, 10/24/22 - Dirty bomb false flag event to IGNITE World War with Russia (2)",
            "n_entries": 2,
            "playlist": "Situation Update, 10/24/22 - Dirty bomb false flag event to IGNITE World War with Russia",
            "playlist_id": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9",
            "playlist_title": "Situation Update, 10/24/22 - Dirty bomb false flag event to IGNITE World War with Russia",
            "playlist_uploader": null,
            "playlist_uploader_id": null,
            "playlist_index": 2,
            "extractor": "generic",
            "webpage_url": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9",
            "webpage_url_basename": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9",
            "extractor_key": "Generic",
            "display_id": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9-2",
            "requested_subtitles": null,
            "ext": "mp3",
            "width": null,
            "height": null,
            "tbr": null,
            "format_id": "0",
            "url": "https://video.brighteon.com/file/BTBucket-Prod/audio/6e8ecf12-f7f8-4565-a8ae-a52c76333556.mp3",
            "vcodec": "none",
            "http_headers": {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3680.1 Safari/537.36",
                "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                "Accept-Language": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
                "Referer": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9"
            },
            "format": "0 - audio only",
            "protocol": "https"
        }
    ],
    "id": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9",
    "title": "Situation Update, 10/24/22 - Dirty bomb false flag event to IGNITE World War with Russia",
    "extractor": "generic",
    "webpage_url": "https://www.brighteon.com/cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9",
    "webpage_url_basename": "cadd23ad-e855-4c1b-ba6d-a605c71a07c9",
    "extractor_key": "Generic"
}
```

I want to modify the json (I need to delete the elements from `json["entries"]` that in `element["ext"]` do not have a video extension) and then use the modified json to download the video; is it possible?, and, in case it is, how?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raise the same question @ ytdl-org [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/31321), and thanks to user **dirkf** I got the answer I needed: after modifying the json, you call make the request with `process_ie_result`, this is an example:

```
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'retries': 10})
result = ydl.extract_info(vurl, download=False)
```

Now, after modifying the json in result, you can download the video with:

```
new_result = ydl.process_ie_result(result, download=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the deepest list (like: result["entries"][0]["formats"][0])

```
for i in result['entries']:
    index=0
    for j in i['formats']:
        if j['ext'] != 'mp4':
            print("Info --- > Deleting: ",i['formats'][index])
            i['formats'].pop(index)
        else:
            pass
        index+=1
```

or if you want to delete main entries dicts (like :result['entries']):

```
for i in result['entries']:
    index=0
    if i['ext'] != 'mp4':
        print("Info --- > Deleting: ",i['formats'][index])
        result['entries'].pop(index)
    else:
        pass
    index+=1
```

*note: result is your json data.*

Comment: Thank you, and, thou this is true, what I need to know is how to use the modified json with youtube-dl in order to only download what is in the modified json.

Comment: So do you need a link ?